# native-image fails to build with google-auth-library-oauth2-http in classpath

Tags: google-oauth, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, google-auth-library

I am trying to build some software using GraalVM's `native-image`. My dependencies include [google-auth-library-oauth2-http](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java). My build fails even when I *don't actually use anything* from the library:

```
➜  gv cat HelloWorld.java
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}

➜  javac HelloWorld.java && native-image -cp google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.20.0.jar -cp . HelloWorld
...
The build process encountered an unexpected error:

> com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError$HostedError: com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Image heap writing found a class not seen during static analysis. Did a static field or an object referenced from a static field change during native image generation? For example, a lazily initialized cache could have been initialized during image generation, in which case you need to force eager initialization of the cache before static analysis or reset the cache using a field value recomputation.
class: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap$Values
  reachable through:
    object: [Ljava.lang.Class;@1668bbd3  of class: java.lang.Class[]
    object: com.oracle.svm.core.code.ImageCodeInfo@1703e50d  of class: com.oracle.svm.core.code.ImageCodeInfo
    root: com.oracle.svm.core.code.ImageCodeInfo.prepareCodeInfo()
```

The library itself seems to come with *some* graalvm resources, so the authors clearly keep this use-case in mind:

```
➜  gv unzip -l google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.20.0.jar | grep .json
    14581  10-04-2023 00:49   META-INF/native-image/com.google.auth/google-auth-library-oauth2-http/reflect-config.json
```

But I can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this is related to "[Reflection in Native Image](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/dynamic-features/Reflection/)

> Native Image has partial support for reflection and needs to know ahead-of-time the reflectively accessed program elements. Examining and accessing program elements through `java.lang.reflect.*` or loading classes with `Class.forName(String)` at run time requires preparing additional metadata for those program elements. (Note: loading classes with `Class.forName(String)` are included here since it is closely related to reflection.)
>
> Native Image tries to resolve the target elements through a static analysis that detects calls to the Reflection API. Where the analysis fails, the program elements reflectively accessed at run time must be specified using a manual configuration.

The error message shows that a class not encountered during the static analysis phase is being used dynamically at runtime, which `native-image` cannot handle by default.

You should try and provide additional configuration to help `native-image` understand and include these dynamically loaded classes. The library does [come with a `reflect-config.json`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/04dfd40c57b89c2d55327d5ea08036d749ebac02/oauth2_http/resources/META-INF/native-image/com.google.auth/google-auth-library-oauth2-http/reflect-config.json), but you might need to extend this configuration to cover all cases.

Try and modify or extend the `reflect-config.json` file in the library to include any missing classes or members that are dynamically accessed.
When building your native image, specify the path to the reflection configuration file using the `-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles` option.

For extending the `reflect-config.json` for `google-auth-library-oauth2-http`, you will need to identify the classes and methods that are accessed reflectively but are not covered in the existing configuration. The error message you encountered gives a hint: `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap$Values`.

Create a new JSON file (named; for instance, `extended-reflect-config.json`) and include entries for the missing classes and their methods.
For the class mentioned in the error, the JSON entry would be:

```json
[
    {
    "name": "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap$Values",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true
    }
    // include other missing classes similarly
]
```

That configuration tells `native-image` to include all constructors and methods (both declared and public) of the specified class.

If there are other configurations in the existing `reflect-config.json`, you should merge them with your `extended-reflect-config.json` to make sure all necessary configurations are included.

When building with `native-image`, reference your `extended-reflect-config.json`:

```bash
native-image -cp google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.20.0.jar -cp . -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=extended-reflect-config.json HelloWorld
```

That process may require some trial and error to identify all the necessary classes and methods.
You can see a similar case study in "[Spring Boot with GraalVM Native Image](https://bell-sw.com/blog/spring-boot-with-graalvm-native-image-performance-compatibility-migration/)" from [Dmitry Chuyko](https://twitter.com/dchuyko).